# Is there a way to search for Registry Keys and Values, export and delete them

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

Im searching for an way to delete the Registry Keys/Values from remote printers, the Keys/Values include the name "(umgeleitet", cause they are slowing down the whole RDP-Sessions. But I want to backup them just in case something gets deleted that shouldn't

I have already tried doing it with `Get-ChildItem` and `Get-ItemProperty`

```
$Folder = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Backup"
Reg export HKU "$Folder\Backup.reg"
Get-ChildItem -path REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\ -Recurse | where { $_.Name -match "(umgeleitet *)"}>> "$Folder\Log.log"
Get-ChildItem -path REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\ -Recurse | where { $_.Name -match "(umgeleitet *)"} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

The code above doesn't delete the Values just the Keys.

Comment: You're looking for [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript).

Comment: Check out [tag:wmi] and the `RegStdProv` class.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Did you accidentally post this comment to the wrong question?

Comment: @LewsTherin No. The OP just deleted the parts of their question I was responding to.

Comment: @LewsTherin No, the original question was about backup and delete the registry Keys / Values ​​and log the whole process which was unnecessary, because it already creates an backup, so I removed that part

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Ahh okay, my mistake. `Start-Transcript` is awesome for logging. Just remember to wrap your code in a `try` block and call `Stop-Transcript` in the `catch` block.

Comment: I removed my answer because as @mklement0 pointed out, you can't use `Copy-Item` to copy between different providers. However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28077331/4416750) shows how to export keys from the registry.

Comment: @LewsTherin If you want to work with `try`/`catch` the `Stop-Transcript` should go into the `finally` block.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You are correct, that was a typo. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

**Exporting**:

Your question already shows the proper solution use: `reg.exe export <key-path> <file>` to export a registry key's subtree to a file.

Note that if you wanted to export the specific keys found as shown below, you'll have to call `reg export` for each, to separate files, given that `reg export` supports only a single target key path, and doesn't support appending to existing files.

Specifically, you could pipe the command below to `reg export` as follows, to create `file1.reg`, `file2.reg`, ... files:

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem -path REGISTRY::... | ForEach-Object { 
  reg.exe export $_.Name "file$(($i++)).reg"
}
```

---

**Locating keys via matching against their *value names***:

```
Get-ChildItem -path REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\ -Recurse | Where-Object { 
  $_.GetValueNames() -match '\(umgeleitet .*\)'
}
```

Note the need to use a proper *regular expression* with `-match`, in which literal `(` and `)` must be `\`-escaped, and in which `.*` represents any sequence of characters.
By contrast, what you used, `(umgeleitet *)`, is a *wildcard expression*, to be used with `-like` (though note that wildcard expressions must match the *entire* input string).

If you wanted to match against value *data*, a little more work would be needed.

---

To **remove** the keys found, simply pipe the above to `Remove-Item`, as in your question:

```
... | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the registry query a tiny bit, to match on the `PSChildName` property, which is shorter and will match a bit faster.

```
$matchingRegKeys = Get-ChildItem -path REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\ -Recurse | where PSChildName -match "(umgeleitet *)"
```

You'll notice I also placed the results into a variable so we can iterate through them with a simple `ForEach` loop.

```
ForEach ($regkey in $matchingRegKeys){
    "Removing $($regkey.Name)" | Tee-Object -Append "$Folder\Log.log"
    $regkey >> "$Folder\Log.log"
    Remove-Item -Path $regkey.PSPath
}
```

The `Tee-Object` command tells PowerShell to both write the output to the screen and also place the items appended into the filepath specified.  Then we write the regkeys values out as well to the file.

Finally, we call `Remove-Item` and provide the `$regkey.PSPath` property, which corresponds to the full path of the key, so you can clear it out and any values.

In operation :

```
Removing HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\umgeleitet
Removing HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\umgeleitet2
Removing HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\umgeleitetTheAwakening
```

And a snip of the log file created:

```
Removing HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\umgeleitet
    Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software
Name                           Property                                                                                           
----                           --------                                                                                           
umgeleitet                     SomeTestValue : true
```

The completed code

```
$Folder = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Backup"
Reg export HKU "$Folder\Backup.reg"
$matchingRegKeys = Get-ChildItem -path REGISTRY::HKEY_USERS\ -Recurse | where PSChildName -match "(umgeleitet *)"

ForEach ($regkey in $matchingRegKeys){
    "Removing $($regkey.Name)" | Tee-Object -Append "$Folder\Log.log"
    $regkey >> "$Folder\Log.log"
    Remove-Item -Path $regkey.PSPath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script alternative to get-itemproperty:

```
# get-itemproperty2.ps1
# get-childitem skips top level key properties, use get-item for that

# example pipe to set-itemproperty:
# ls -r hkcu:\key1 | get-itemproperty2 | where value -match value | 
#   set-itemproperty -value myvalue -whatif

param([parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$key)

process { 
  $valuenames = $key.getvaluenames() 

  if ($valuenames) { 
    $valuenames | foreach {
      $value = $_
      [pscustomobject] @{
        Path = $key -replace 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER',
          'HKCU:' -replace 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','HKLM:'
        Name = $Value
        Value = $Key.GetValue($Value)
        Type = $Key.GetValueKind($Value)
      }
    }
  } else {
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Path = $key -replace 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER',
        'HKCU:' -replace 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','HKLM:'
        Name = ''
        Value = ''
        Type = ''
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can do things like:

```
ls -r hkcu:\key1 | .\get-itemproperty2 | where value -match value

Path                 Name  Value     Type
----                 ----  -----     ----
HKCU:\key1\key2      name2 myvalue String
HKCU:\key1\key2\key3 name3 myvalue String


ls -r hkcu:\key1 | .\get-itemproperty2 | where value -match value | Remove-ItemProperty -WhatIf
What if: Performing the operation "Remove Property" on target "Item: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\key1\key2 Property: name2".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove Property" on target "Item: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\key1\key2\key3 Property: name3".
```